# Eclipse DTP - Microsoft Sql Server Connection

Tags: sql-server, eclipse

I am trying to setup connection in Eclipse DTP with Microsoft SQLServer 2014.
I followed various steps I found on net but none of them worked so far.
This is what I did:

1. Downloaded drivers from:[Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774)
2. Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Data Management > Connectivity > Driver Definitions, selected: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 JDBC Driver
3. Edit > JAR List > C:\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar

[image]

4. Properties: 
   [image]
5. Apply and close
6. Change perspective to: Database Development
7. Right click on Database Connections > New > SQL Server, click on Triangle Symbol for "Edit Driver Definition" 
   [image]

Checked that everything is set as in previous steps, but "Next" and "Finish buttons are still grayed out.
[image]

Do I miss some step? What I have to do to enable "Next" or "Finish" button?
I've tried clicking "New driver definition" but without success.